# Isn't Limsup a Banach Limit?

Tags: banach-spaces, limsup-and-liminf, hahn-banach-theorem

Wikipedia says that we need the axiom of choice to prove that Banach Limits exist:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

Isn't the map $\limsup:l_\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ a Banach limit?
Why would we then need the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\lim \sup$ is not linear so it is not a Banach limit.

Comment: Oh shit, thanks.